# Find and replace in string

Tags: php

Hi Folks Please  Help me out on this.

```
$string='1. New ‘benami’ Act to take effect from Nov. [Governance]
1. The Benami Transactions (Prohibition) Amendment Act will come into force 2. New ‘benami’ Act to take effect from Nov. [Governance]
2. The Benami Transactions (Prohibition) Amendment Act will come into force';

for($i=1;$i<=8;$i++)
{
    $string = str_replace($i.'.', "<li>", $string);
}
echo  $string;
```

Above code replace all 1. with li but i need to replace  first 1. with h3 and  second 1. with li and so on

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you actually want as you've simplified the example in your question too much.

But based on what you've given, try something like this:

```
$stringArray = split('1. ', $string);
$h3 = array_shift($string);
$h3 = "<h3>".$h3."</h3>";
foreach ($stringArray as $key => &$string) {
    $stringarray[$key] = "<li>".$string."</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is break it up into an array of items, then put it back together with the pieces wrapped in the appropriate tags

```
$array = preg_split('/\d+\. / ', $string);
echo '<h3>' . $array[1] . '</h3><li>' . implode('</li><li>', array_slice($array, 2)) . '</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $string='1. New ‘benami’ Act to take effect from Nov. [Governance] 1. The Benami Transactions (Prohibition) Amendment Act will come into force   ........';
   $string=trim($string);             
   $Arr=explode("1.",$string);
   array_filter($Arr);
   $string="<h3>".$Arr[1]."</h3><li>".$Arr[2]."</li>";
   echo $string;


 Below link for output

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6qZp.png
```

Comment: You want to replace only 1. with <h3> and another 1. with <li> am i right??

Comment: your code works perfectly but i need this recursively Means

Comment: recursive means excluding 1. (i.e) 2. 3. 4. like these. am i right?